# OpenOffice access a table from an odb (HSQLDB) file

Tags: mysql, openoffice-calc, odb

I got an external Access database imported with OpenOffice and saved by OpenOffice as .odb file. However I can't access the data from my OpenOffice Calc table fields:

```
='filename.odb'#tablename.A0
```

does not import anything. Is there a special trick about that ?
I can't find any solutions on how to solve this issue. Even using the row and column names instead of `A0` does not work. I can't believe I have to code like a whole function to read values from HSQLDB databases into my table fields.
The common way on importing parts of external tables in OpenOffice like the above code aren't working.

I also tried to add a database link within my spreadsheet and access it with its name:

```
='databasename'#tablename.A0
```

but that ditn't work either. Also using the row name instead of `A0` which is `ID` in my case. What I want to do is perform `VLOOKUP` functions on the external table to obtain some product IDs and product descriptions. I can view the external database by pressing F4. So importing it kinda worked.
The only solution that works is copy+paste the required tables into new OpenOffice documents and accessing them with the default OpenOffice functions.

Comment: Can you access the table using OpenOffice Base? Is the database registered in openoffice? Which version of Openoffice are you using?, Which OS?

Comment: Yes, the table is registered, I can open it with tools->options->databases. Also pressing F4 opens the table in a separate window area.

Comment: The biggest problem is the dumbness of some coders implementing german code syntax within the german version, because I'm switching between english and german versions of this computer and my notebook. Can you imagine how that sucks, translating every function name back and forth when testing ?

Comment: My OpenOffice version is 3.4.1